# Background service work instead the main activity

Tags: android, android-activity, service, background

I am have main activity (to-do list application) that also call to background Service and this Service call to some GooglePlacesActivity class. the problem is when the Service is on the application go to the GooglePlacesActivity instead of doing this activity in the background and do the main activity as it should to do.
I will be happy if you can explain to me why this is happened and how I can fix this problem.

( I have two activities and one service. the main activity need to work in the front and the service need to call to the second activity and do the second activity in the background )

Background Service -

```
public class BackgroundProcess extends Service {

public GooglePlacesActivity PlacesActivity;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Let it continue running until it is stopped.

    Intent in=new Intent().setClass(BackgroundProcess.this,GooglePlacesActivity.class);
    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(in);
    return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't start activity as a service. I think that you wanna try to do maybe. Didn't really understand your question.

Comment: @KrupalShah I have two activities and one service. the main activity need to work in the front and the service need to call to the second activity and do the second activity in the background

Comment: what do you mean by "do the second activity in the background". Activity controls the user interaction. can't something that can run in background

Comment: @KrupalShah The second activity is google maps search activity and i want it to be in the background. so you say that I need to make this process in the service module ? Or there is another option to make this possible ?

Comment: Activities are not intended for background work. Your service can do background work, just do your search there on a background thread (or extend `IntentService` instead of `Service`).

Comment: @Karakuri Ok thanks I use this method ( ;